# Rails - undefined method using Draper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, draper

I have this model called " Barber " .

I have installed Draper like so

```
gem 'draper', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.2'
then 
bundle install
then 
rails generate decorator Barber
```

This is the Decorator class

```
include Draper::LazyHelpers
class BarberDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def fullname
    object.first_name + "Barber"
  end

end
```

I want it to add "Barber" to the first_name column when I display it my `barbers/index.html.erb` file

Here is the code for that view.

```
<tbody>
    <% @barbers.each do |barber| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= barber.first_name.decorate%></td>
        <td><%= barber.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= barber.age %></td>
        <td><%= barber.email %></td>
        <td><%= barber.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', barber %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_barber_path(barber) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', barber, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

I try to use the decorator by calling it on this line `<td><%= barber.first_name.decorate%></td>`

But it throws this error.

```
NoMethodError in Barbers#index
undefined method `decorate' for "test2":String
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

**UPDATE**
I have now tried this in my `controllers/barbers_controller.rb`

```
 def show
    @barber = Barber.find(params[:id]).decorate
    
  end
```

Then when I go to show.html.erb

```
<th scope="row"><%= @barber.first_name.fullname %></th>
```

I get this error

```
Could not infer a decorator for Barber.
Extracted source (around line #14):
12
13
14
15
16
17
              
  # GET /barbers/1 or /barbers/1.json
  def show
    @barber = Barber.find(params[:id]).decorate
    
  end
```

Comment: Please elaborate , I find this decorator very confusing...

Comment: I get that but where in my code exactly do I call the methods?

Comment: I think I figured it out now, I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion in the comment section and more digging , here is what I done to have it working correctly.

```
#In my barbers controller

def index
    @barbers = Barber.all.decorate
end
```

Then in my view

```
<td><%= barber.barber %></td>
```

Where .barber is the name of my method inside my `barber_decorator.rb` file.